# vi copy entire line in PuTTY

Tags: putty, vi

I have a very long XML string in a line of a log in vi/PuTTY. It is too long to drag the mouse over to copy to clipboard. Is there a shortcut to select/copy to clipboard the entire line? I do not want to copy the entire file, just this one long line to paste into Notepad++ or Sublime Text.

I found `yy` [here](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/vi.html) but it did not work.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9166363/3565972 . You need to yank the line not into vim's clipboard, but to the system clipboard, which should be register `*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to copy the whole line, then the easiest way is to select the whole line and then yank it.

In normal mode, <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>$</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>.

This translates to, "Go to the beginning of the line; select to the end of the line; yank."

Comment: This is equivalent to `yy`. I think (not sure though) that the OP is trying to copy the line to the system clipboard. Otherwise, `yy` should have worked.

Comment: Well, `yy` doesn't copy the whole line for me in `vim`. Perhaps that deals with the register issue discussed by the post @savanto mentioned. But, the command I posted does work, at least, for me.

Answer (score 0):

You realize that you can write either a line or a series of lines to another file while in vi using command mode:

1. While editing enter the following to copy the current line to another file: (note the period before the w command)

   :.w filename

You can then use :.r to read in the line(s) wherever you want.